# Why max heuristic is inacurrate?

Tags: search-algorithms, heuristics

H_max() algorithms work by considering a state in the planning graph, and using all applicable actions to make every atom in that state true. The h_max() for a given state is the cost of the most expensive atom in that state. Lets say that we have a relaxed planning task and it's heuristic (h+) then c*h_max()

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Can you give us some more context?  What do you mean by the max heuristic?  What problem are you trying to use it to solve?  What's the context where you encountered this heuristic?

Comment: Please edit the question to make your question self-contained.  Don't just post clarifications in the comments; we want people to be able to understand what you are asking, based on what is in the question alone (without having to read the comments).  Thank you!